# Find custom program accounts

Tags: getprogramaccounts

How can I find all accounts of my wallet which is owned by a specific program? (Not any of the metaplex programs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon the logic of the program. If the program saves the wallet address as a field inside accounts, you can use a filter while fetching.

Example:

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyAccount {
    owner: pubkey,
    data: u64
}
```

To fetch all the accounts of type `MyAccount` having let say, pubkey: XXXX as their owner, you can use something like this:

```
const accounts = await program.account.myAccount.all(
    [
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 8
            bytes: XXXX
          }
        }
    ]
)
```